# PayPal Smart Button shipping issue

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am using the paypal smart buttoin whihc all seems to work fine.
However i want to be able to update shipping costs so did a small test first with teh following code...

```
onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {
if (data.shipping_address.country_code !== 'GB') {
    return actions.reject();
}
```

However this is really incosistant, it will sometimes work fine and when selected a non GB address will say we do not ship to this address in the paypal popup, but for instance if you press the paypal button again on my website the next time the paypal window no longer updates the shipping so you can select any country without it stopping you.

Am i missing something , the above small piece of code seems really basic.

Comment: It worked fine in my test -- popup asked to changed address, closed popup, pressed PayPal button again, and was also asked to changed address. What else is needed to reproduce?

Comment: Yeh thats what it is suppose to do, is it possible as i use cloudflare it is somehow blocking response sometimes ?

Comment: im also using in sandbox can this be issue with sessions or similar ?

Comment: i have added image to imgur as not sure how to show it here...  https://imgur.com/a/ko5KoDu                         so as you can see the log console is showing `reject` but the paypal popup remains and has the buy now button at bottom so its not actually rejecting on the popup , its like its rejecting but not actually actioning it on the popup.